# Is it possible to authenticate Indian unfair aadhar by openid protocol

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop application in spring mvc to authenticate India aadhar db using openid protocol.any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your *specific* issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't but they have java api to communicate through there aadhar uidai db.Please follow the link to more details
https://developer.uidai.gov.in/site/book/export/html/18

Comment: Thanks will use and ask if any problem

Comment: @user5820450 your welocme.